# error while installing riak from source

Tags: ruby, linux, riak

```
make rel
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
./rebar get-deps
/usr/bin/env: escript: No such file or directory
make: *** [deps] Error 127
```

This is the error I got when I tried to install riak from source.  Can someone please help me?

Comment: Type `escript` and what do you get?  You need to have erlang installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you are missing erlang from your path or not installed.

```
 escript  ## Should return escript: Missing filename
```

Locate erlang look under /usr/local/bin or /opt/erlang/

```
 echo $PATH
```

If it's not in your path then add it.

Comment: sorry i cant understand what is escript? i can't find any erlang how to install it ?

Comment: riak is written in the eralng programming language, you mush have erlang installed to build riak.  Try to follow these instructions `http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/installation/` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I am using centos6 i cant find any packages of erlang for it

Comment: can u please help me out in installing erlang?

Comment: Here are the instructions for installing to CentOS `http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/installation/Installing-on-RHEL-and-CentOS/` scroll down to see the instructions for CentOS6